# Why does adding another WHERE clause change the type of my sql statement variable?

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I am a bit stumped with what happens here. I'm working on a challenge for an online programming course and the solution involves adding a second where statement to the sql query.
when I do this, however, python gives me a typeerror, saying "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable".
I'm pretty sure this is because the fetchone()[1] at the end requires a list or tuple to retrieve the ID. what I don't understand is why adding the second bit of the WHERE clause would change the type of the result.
I have checked the statement itself and it works when testing it on the database, and the first link_id statement in the code below works fine, it returns an int object but the second gives an error. It should return a similar int object.

```
link_id = self.cursor.execute(self.sql_select + " WHERE " + self.field + "=?", (value,)).fetchone()[1]

print("link_id type:", type(link_id))

link_id = self.cursor.execute(self.sql_select + " WHERE " + self.field + "=? AND albums.artist=?", (value, self.artist_id)).fetchone()[1]

print("link_id type:", type(link_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

it was because self.artist_id was None. it reset when running this block of code again.